Dynamic Height Cell with XIB: Including UILabel and UIImageView
I’m trying to design a UITableViewCell with XIB that has the following layout and behavior:

A UIView on the left with a fixed size of 44x44.
A UILabel next to it, which expands dynamically based on the text length.
A UIImageView below the label, which resizes its height proportionally to its maximum width (maintaining aspect ratio).

Unfortunately, I can’t get this to work properly with Auto Layout. I keep running into issues with either dynamic sizing not working as expected or constraint errors.
Here’s an illustration of the layout I am trying to achieve:

Requirements:
1. UIView:
Fixed size: 44x44.
Positioned on the left.
2. UILabel:
Should expand dynamically in width and height based on the text length.
3. UIImageView:
Should stretch to the maximum width of the cell.
The height should be proportional to the width (e.g., maintaining a 16:9 aspect ratio).
-> To achieve this layout, I need guidance on:
What constraints should I define for UIView, UILabel, and UIImageView in XIB to ensure proper behavior?
How can I make the UILabel expand dynamically based on its content while ensuring the cell height adjusts correctly?
How can I make the UIImageView responsive, maintaining its aspect ratio while fitting the maximum width of the cell?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

"1. UIView: Fixed size: 44x44. Positioned on the left. Vertically centered in the cell." ... Do you mean vertically centered on the height of the UILabel?

I apologize for the confusion. I’ve revised the explanation: I just want to position it at the top-left corner with a fixed height and width.

If you want to do this in a XIB, it is fairly straightforward using a horizontal UIStackView to hold the 44x44 view and the label, and vertical UIStackView to hold that stack view and the UIImageView...

Set the horizontal stack view properties to:

and the vertical stack view properties to:

for each, adjust the Spacing as desired.
Note that the bottom constraint on the vertical stack view has its Priority set to 999 ... that prevents auto-layout complaints, both at design-time and run-time.
Looks like this when running:



Here is my example in code how to constraint your cell:
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    let squareView = UIView()
    let label = UILabel()
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.addSubview(squareView)
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        contentView.addSubview(imgView)
        squareView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = "fasdfdsf sdf"
        squareView.backgroundColor = .red
        imgView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            squareView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            squareView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            squareView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 47),
            squareView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 47),
            
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: squareView.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: squareView.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.4)
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

Case with long text in label:

Case with short text in label:

A notable thing here is the use of constraint greater from topAnchor of imgView to bottomAnchor of both label and squareView, these 2 constraints will make sure your imgView always stay in bottom of squareView and label regardless of text height.
You can add constaint ratio in Interface Builder from below:

